# How can i save shortcut in python if target path conatains nonascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pythoncom

If the path target path contains `nonascii`, saving getting failed if it contains `ascii` then it works.

```
def CreateShortcut(shortcutDir, shortcutName, targetPath, iconPath, iconIdx):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    shll = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
    shortcut = shll.CreateShortCut(shortcutDir.GetChild("%s.lnk" % shortcutName).path)
    shortcut.Targetpath = GetFolderShortPath(targetPath.path)
    shortcut.IconLocation = GetFileShortPath(iconPath.path)
    shortcut.save()
```

in this shortcut failing to interpret path because it contains non ascii path , how could i resolve this

If i enable "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" then it works , what code changes should i make if i disable the beta checkbox and target path contains non ascii

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share all `import`s, a sample call and how it fails (error or [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake))…